# Java I/O: differences between Java SE 6 and 7?

Tags: java, io

I'm studying for a Java SE 6 test, and one of the topics is "Java I/O". I started reading the official tutorial, but when it comes to [File I/O (Featuring NIO.2)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) it says

> Note: This tutorial reflects the file I/O mechanism introduced in the JDK 7 release. The Java SE 6 version of the File I/O tutorial was brief, but you can download the [Java SE Tutorial 2008-03-14](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-tutorials-419421.html#tutorial-2008_03_14-oth-JPR) version of the tutorial which contains the earlier File I/O content.

I went at that link and downloaded the Tutorial (which is dated **2010-10-18** however...), but at the very same page it says...

> This section was updated to reflect features and conventions of the upcoming Java SE 7 release. You can download the current JDK7 snapshot from java.net.
>   The Java SE 6 version of the File I/O tutorial was brief, but you can download the [Java SE Tutorial 2008-03-14](https://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewProductDetail-Start?ProductRef=tutorial-2008_03_14-oth-JPR@CDS-CDS_Developer) version of the tutorial which contains the earlier File I/O content.

Could you help me to locate the correct document for Java 6? Or I can just totally skip that section? I don't want to end mixing up Java 6 and Java 7 features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could you help me to find the correct one for Java 6?

Pass.  (Off-topic)

> Or I can just totally skip that section?

Nope.  I would advise that you revise based on the Java 7 tutorial.

> I don't want to end mixing up Java 6 and Java 7 features.

I wouldn't worry about it.  If that is a concern, you can:

- Check the javadocs to see if the relevant classes and methods were added in Java 7.
- Read the Java 7 "what is new" documentation on the I/O changes.

Comment: I know that's forbidden asking for tutorials, but that's different, I'm looking for THAT, EXACT Oracle official document that's missing. I'm still looking for a way other than looking in jdk6 for every class used in the tutorial...

Comment: If Google can't find it, and the Internet Archive can't find it, then it probably doesn't exist anymore (except on Oracle's backup tapes).  Anyhow, I'm not going to look for it for you ... 'cos >>I<< think it is off-topic.

Comment: I agree with you. Except for the off-topic part =)